# Test in Postman to check that the From-To number is returned

Tags: rest, testing, postman

There is a query that returns the length of the key:

```
GET https://apitest.backendless.com/A1DA5DF0-8D22-BAC4-FF56-9A0074DC9B00/8834B7F8-88BD-4472-9051-71BE31A3EE5B/hive/rootKeys/set//UniversalKey9/length
```

My test checks that the length of the string is 5.

```
let response = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Length key (int)", () => {
    pm.expect(response, "Error").to.eql(5)
})
```

But the length can change, then the test will fail, how to write a test so that it checks the length of the string from 1 to 99, while "0" should not be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use chai.js `above` and `below` chained together. Assuming `response` already holds the length, the test will work like this:

```js
let response = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Length key (int) between 1 and 99", () => {
    pm.expect(response).to.be.above(0).below(100)
})
```

I've created a sample Postman Request that you can open and copy, that on each request generates a `randomInt` and tests it out. You can [check it here](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/request/19391207-bcedb105-45e6-453c-84fd-1bcd087051bd). Or if you want the source of my test with the `randomInt` it looks like this:

```js
const response = Number(pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomInt}}'))

pm.test("Length key (int) between 1 and 99", () => {
    pm.expect(response).to.be.above(0).below(100)
})
```

These are some example requests, and the result of the test:

[image]